# Tensorflow - saving the model generated in the PC to be used in the mobile version of Tensorflow or OpenCV

Tags: opencv, tensorflow

Currently I'm still working on that age classification project using the Convolutional Neural Network built in Tensorflow. How, and in what format, do I save the state of my current model trained in my PC to be able to use said model in the Tensorflow in my mobile app, or even OpenCV's tiny-dnn (dnn_modern)? Because I'm not sure if the checkpoint file would work in OpenCV's tiny-dnn.

Comment: Not clear what you need exactly. Do u need to deploy a Tensorflow model to Android?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Other than the Tensorflow for Android, I heard I can use OpenCV's dnn_modern module (using tiny-dnn) to load some Tensorflow models.

Comment: @Gensoukyou1337, Actually model is called just dnn. Take a look on this tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d6c/tutorial_dnn_android.html .